# Get standard deviation of a distribution made by subtracting two distributions with known standard deviations

Tags: statistics

I have some data

D1 (N=4)    D2 (N=4)

Unfortunately, I don't have the data points. I only have the statistics:

(mean d1,mean d2) = (2.5,8)

(SD1,SD2 (standard deviation))= (1.290994449,1.414213562)

I can compute:
   (SE1,    SE2 (standard error)) = (0.322748612,0.353553391)

My problem is that I need to find the mean and standard deviation of D1-D2 = d11-d21,d12-d22,d13-d23,d14-d24.

The mean is easy: meand1-meand2.

But how to find the standard deviation of the new distribution???

Now,

D1
3
2
1
4

D2
8
7
7
10

Diff
5
5
6
6

meanDiff
5.5
SDDiff
0.577350269
seDiff
0.144337567

but

sqrt(1.290994449* 1.290994449 + 1.414213562* 1.414213562) = 1.914854216 != 0.577350269

Comment: I think that to compute mean of differences is also not possible without original data (the argument is in my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

If the two random variables are independent with means $\mu_{D_1}$ and $\mu_{D_2}$ and standard deviations  $\sigma_{D_1}$ and $\sigma_{D_2}$ then the mean of the difference is the difference of the means, as you have said, so   $\mu_{D_1-D_2}=\mu_{D_1}-\mu_{D_2}$, while the variance of the difference is the sum of the variances $\sigma^2_{D_1-D_2}=\sigma^2_{D_1}+\sigma^2_{D_2}$, so the standard deviation of the difference is the square-root of this $$\sigma_{D_1-D_2}=\sqrt{\sigma^2_{D_1}+\sigma^2_{D_2}}.$$

If they are not independent (if you are using sample data then the sample data is unlikely to be uncorrelated) than you cannot say this, though you can if you think appropriate assume it about the underlying distributions.

Comment: I think the problem concerns descriptive statistics, not random variables.

Comment: @mcihak: you may be correct.  But even with descriptive statistics there can be assumptions, such as the statistics used in an unpaired or paired *t*-test

Comment: Yes, this is true. However it seems to me that in the above problem the order of the data is important. If we shuffle the data within groups, descriptive statistics of the individual groups do not change, but the differences change (differences are dependent on the order of values in groups). For example, it is not possible to shuffle data for paired t-test (data must be paired).

Comment: @Sam: your data is correlated

Comment: @Sam: That's what I said. If you change order of D1: 3, 2, 1, 4 for example to D1: 2, 3, 1, 4 then SD of D1 does not change but differences change to 6, 4, 6, 6 and it's clear that SD of differences also change. So I say again: It is not possible to calculate mean and SD of differences without original data.

Comment: @mcihak The mean of the difference is the difference of the means even with arbitrary descriptive statistics, because addition is commutative and associative.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible without original data. Imagine that we know the original data and we change the order of data in the first group. After that mean and standard deviation of this group do not change but differences $d_{11}-d_{21},d_{12}-d_{22},d_{13}-d_{23},d_{14}-d_{24}$ change (because of different order  ).